# How to get value of object with array of column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newbie on RoR. I have an array of columns and users like this :

```
@user_form_column_list = 
[#<MUserForm:0x0000560565e976c0
  user_form_id: 1401,
  site_id: 1071,
  filed_name: "Kana",
  db_column_name: "last_name",
  input_type: nil,
  input_rqrd: 1,
  order_num: 1,
  status_flg: 1>,
#<MUserForm:0x0000560565e976c0
  user_form_id: 1402,
  site_id: 1071,
  filed_name: "Kanaaa",
  db_column_name: "first_name",
  input_type: nil,
  input_rqrd: 1,
  order_num: 1,
  status_flg: 1>,...]
@users = 
[#<TUser:0x00007f107d74a6f0
  user_id: 11034,
  site_id: 1071,
  user_email: "pham.yen.vy+user2@gmail.com",
  last_name: nil,
  first_name: nil>,
#<TUser:0x00007f107d74a6f0
  user_id: 11035,
  site_id: 1071,
  user_email: "pham.yen.vy+user1@gmail.com",
  last_name: nil,
  first_name: nil>,...]
```

In views:
index.html.erb:

```erb
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table_top" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="60">&nbsp;</th>
    <% @user_form_column_list.each do |column| %>
      <th><%= column.filed_name %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <%= render "t_user" %>
</table>
```

_t_user.html.erb:

```erb
<% @users.each.with_index do |user. index| %>
<tr>
<td>
  <div align="center">
    <%= link_to "link" do %>
      <input type="button" value="編集">
    <% end %>
  </div>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><%=  %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

So, My question: How to display the correct value with the corresponding fields in file _t_user.html.erb?

Comment: Hi, Your question is not clear. Please add more detail about what fields you want to show on the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple, for each user you have to loop through the columns to display.

```erb
<% @user.each do |user| %>
  <% @user_form_column_list.each do |column| %>
    <%= user[column.db_column_name] # assuming the db_column_name holds the user attribute %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I left out any HTML to simplify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, from your example input/output you can do something like:

```
TUser.pluck(:user_id, :name, :age)
```

Comment: sorry because I write not clear. I will edit my question